# Copying Primary key to another field in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-office

Hey, I'm struggling to copy the Primary Key to another field in Access. 
This is irrelevant , but clarifying on what I'm comparing.

```
... WHERE Tunniste=" & [Tarkiste] & ""
```

Tunniste = Primary Key , Autonumber , ID (Generated by Access.)

Tarkiste = This is the field I want to copy it to compare it.

I'm open to suggestions, I've already try'ed with Form_Load, using the following code.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Korut SET [Tarkiste]=('" & Tunniste & "');"

End Sub
```

But this copied the same key to all the entries in "Tarkiste" field.

In simplicity I want 1:1 copy of field "Tunniste" to "Tarkiste" , whichever method it takes.

Started from this question. [File Picker Replaces All Rows With The Same Choice.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735533/access-2007-file-picker-replaces-all-rows-with-the-same-choice)

Comment: @BashLover: I gave +1 to Toni for correct answer, but I suggest that you read my answer as there are a few points that you might find useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two fields are in the same table, you can do this:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Korut SET [Tarkiste]=[Tunniste]"
```

And its sure that it runs!

Comment: Thanks it worked, this community rocks =)  I'm surely going to help out other people on my field of knowledge on unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

To better grasp what is happening is

The single value gets updated in every row because your query's string is calculated when the form loads.
At that time the variable `Tunniste` gets a value from the control it is bound to (in your case probably the control that points to the field in the recordset of the same table).

So assuming Tunniste is 1 for the current record on Form_Load the database ends up running a query

```
UPDATE Korut SET [Tarkiste]=('1');
```

where

```
UPDATE Korut SET [Tarkiste]=[Tunniste];
```

will do a proper thing.

Things to notice:

- you can (should) test and construct your SQL command independently of form events (especially if non of the query parameters depend on the values in the form, bound or unbound); running SQL happens in its own space
- use visual query builder to practice your SQL skills (switch to SQL mode and back to understand what happens)
- read up on how the data is bound to the form
- you are updating all records in the table every time a form loads and (if this is a normal edit form) this is certainly not optimal (you could at least add a WHERE condition to SET the [Tarkiste] only in case the values are different), this will scale poorly
- you seem to be using different data types for the same field and silent conversion; this can backfire

Maybe explaining what is it that you are trying to achieve will bring better advice.